# Unparsable date exception

Tags: java, date, exception

I'm currently working on some simple project in `Java` and I have date in the following string:

```
String dateString = "Sun 7/14 03:44 AM 2013";
```

and want to to convert this string to `Date` object. I'm using following lines of code to do that. I searched site and found solution how to do this with `DateFormatter`:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M/dd hh:mm a yyyy");
Date d = format.parse(dateString);
```

But I'm probably doing something wrong, because I always get exception:

```
Unparseable date: "Sun 7/14 03:44 AM 2013"
```

This seems to be problem with pattern I'm using but tried different patterns and nothing work.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is pretty clear about the formats you can use :)

Comment: I know but I cant figure out why it is not working...:/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain fields such as the day of week fields and/or AM/PM marker may not match those from  your default `Locale`. `ParseException` has the method [getErrorOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html#getErrorOffset%28%29) to determine exactly where the pattern does not match.

try

```
DateFormat format = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M/dd hh:mm a yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: You might want to change the String to "EEE MM/dd hh:mm a yyyy" before October.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to add `Locale` as you are parsing language day of week names.

```
String dateString = "Sun 7/14 03:44 AM 2013";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M/dd hh:mm a yyyy", Locale.US);
Date d = format.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and the following worked,

```
        String stringDate = "Sun 7/14 03:44 AM 2013";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM/dd hh:mm a yyyy");

        System.out.println("Parsed Date = "+format.parse(stringDate));
```

The output was as follows

```
Parsed Date = Sun Jul 14 03:44:00 BST 2013
```

Comment: It works with english locale settings only, it does not for Majky as has different locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("/* type your own format*/");



  String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);

  System.out.println("Formatted date is ==>"+formattedDate);
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

The modern answer for the sake of completeness. While the other answers were good answers in 2013, `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` are now long outdated, and I recommend you replace them with their modern counterparts:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parser 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE M/dd hh:mm a yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, parser);
```

The result is a `LocalDateTime` of `2013-07-14T03:44` as expected.

The format pattern string is still the same, and the need for an English language locale is the same.